# Where can i find a golden chocobo? Available in gold saucer?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I started playing ff7 because of a friend and he said i need a golden chocoboo to get a materia.

Where can i find it? Is it expensive? Can i also use it in the gold saucer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't find a Golden Chocobo, you have to breed it. The process is time consuming and exhausting, so prepare yourself for hours of birds mating and races (because you have to train them too).

The complete process can be found [in this guide](http://www.ehow.com/how_18493_breed-golden-chocobo.html) explained quite in detail.

To sum it up you have to:

- Get two good yellow chocobos
- Train them to class A in the golden saucer
- make them breed and get a Blue and Green chocobo (they have to be of different gender)
- make them breed and get a black chochobo
- train it to class S
- make it breed with a class A chocobo
- finally obtain a Golden chocobo

Inbetween you'll have to find various objects to feed to your chocobos, and various things are completely random (such as the gender of the chocobo you'll get). Be patient and your reward will come!

Oh, and obviously you can use it in the Golden Saucer, it's simply the best Chocobo you can get. It can also cross any terrain on the map, including water.

Another way to get a Golden Chocobo that I just discovered is to get the Desert Rose, the reward from the Ruby Weapon, to the [Kalm Traveler](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Kalm_Traveler). Depending on your group and skills, this way could be less painful.

Comment: Unfortunately the main use of the Gold Chocobo is to get the Knights of the Round, the main use of which is to kill Ruby and Emerald Weapon.

Comment: @BenBrocka actually I used Knights of the round just for the Emerald. With the Ruby I got lucky, after 5 combats ended with my whole party being sucked out, I managed to kill it with just Cloud standing.

Comment: @Kappei what you're *supposed* to do is start with just one player standing and revive them after he lowers his tentacles; he doesn't remove players from combat when his tentacles are out. But I never managed to beat him without KotR because I never knew that tip until this year :P

Comment: @kappei For the best stats use two great chocobos, and you breed the black chochobo with a Wonderful chochobo for best results.